Why does view.on('click') event not fire and popup not open
I am trying to add a popup to a very simple web app using the arcGIS Map SDK for JS and React. The popup is not opening and when I check the debugger, it looks like the `view.on('click', ...) event is not firing. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong and how I might fix this. My goal is to have a popup that displays the lat and lon coordinates.
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import FeatureLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/FeatureLayer';
import Map from '@arcgis/core/Map';
import MapView from '@arcgis/core/views/MapView';

function ESRIMap() {
  // Map Component using ArcGIS SDK 
  const mapDiv = useRef(null); 

  useEffect(() => {
      const map = new Map({
        basemap: 'dark-gray',
      });

      const view = new MapView({
        container: mapDiv.current,
        map: map,
        center: [-76.0, 38.0],
        zoom: 3,
      }); 

      const countyBoundaries = new FeatureLayer({
        url: 'https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Counties/FeatureServer/0',
      });

      map.add(countyBoundaries);

      view.popupEnabled = false;
      view.on('click', (event) => {
        const lt = event.mapPoint.latitude.toFixed(4);
        const ln = event.mapPoint.longitude.toFixed(4);
    
        view.openPopup({
          title: 'X, Y Coords',
          content: `Latitude: ${lt}<br>Logitude: ${ln}`,
          location: event.mapPoint,
        });
      });

      return () => {
        if (view) {
          view.destroy();
        }
      };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={mapDiv} style={{height:'700px',width:'100%'}} id="map" className="mapDiv" />
  );
}

export default ESRIMap;


Not sure if this is the issue, but I think the correct popup call could be view.popup.open not view.openPopup
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import FeatureLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/FeatureLayer';
import Map from '@arcgis/core/Map';
import MapView from '@arcgis/core/views/MapView';

function ESRIMap() {
  // Map Component using ArcGIS SDK 
  const mapDiv = useRef(null); 

  useEffect(() => {
      const map = new Map({
        basemap: 'dark-gray',
      });

      const view = new MapView({
        container: mapDiv.current,
        map: map,
        center: [-76.0, 38.0],
        zoom: 3,
      }); 

      const countyBoundaries = new FeatureLayer({
        url: 'https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Counties/FeatureServer/0',
      });

      map.add(countyBoundaries);

      view.popupEnabled = false;
      view.on('click', (event) => {
        const lt = event.mapPoint.latitude.toFixed(4);
        const ln = event.mapPoint.longitude.toFixed(4);
    
        view.popup.open({
          title: 'X, Y Coords',
          content: `Latitude: ${lt}<br>Longitude: ${ln}`,
          location: event.mapPoint,
        });
      });

      return () => {
        if (view) {
          view.destroy();
        }
      };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={mapDiv} style={{height:'700px',width:'100%'}} id="map" className="mapDiv" />
  );
}

export default ESRIMap;

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html
